# Matlab Solve Symbolic Function after rearranging for new subject

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have this formula that I use to calculate Vo given Ps AND it can be re-arranged for Ps given Vo:

```
Vo=(Ps)*(BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd
```

I want to make a versatile function for this purpose in MATLAB. I start by declaring a symbolic function and solving it with numerical substitutions this way:

```
syms Ps BWc BWs Ro n LdB Rpd;
Vo(Ps,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd)=(Ps)*(BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd;
Vo(250,0.12,1000,0.01,4,0.5,75)
```

I want to be able to re-arrange the symbolic function for Ps and solve again:

```
 Ps(Vo,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd)= solve('Vo=(Ps)*(BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd','Ps');
 Ps(0.0063,0.12,1000,0.01,4,0.5,75)
```

However the above two lines do not work. I get the error for the last line above: "Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values." I have also tried:

```
syms Vo Ps BWc BWs Ro n LdB Rpd;
Vo(Ps,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd)=(Ps)*(BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd;
Vo(250,0.12,1000,0.01,4,0.5,75)
Ps(Vo,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd)=(Vo)/((BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd);
Ps(0.0063,0.12,1000,0.01,4,0.5,75)
```

What is the correct way to use the symbolic toolbox for this purpose?

Comment: You appear to be evaluating this numerically. The function is trivial to solve symbolically – is it just an example? Do you actually need to use symbolic math? Why not just make a regular function with an argument that indicates if you want it to return `Vo` or `Ps` (and thus are input the other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be because you have a variable called `Vo` and you're also using `Vo` to define a function. You can't do that and still use both. It's effectively an issue of [variable scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). Here's how you can successfully use `solve`:

```
syms Vo Ps BWc BWs Ro n LdB Rpd;
Vo_fun(Ps,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd) = Ps*(BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd
Vo_fun(250,0.12,1000,0.01,4,0.5,75)
Ps_fun(Vo,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd) = solve(Vo==Vo_fun,Ps)
Ps_fun(0.0063,0.12,1000,0.01,4,0.5,75)
```

I don't see the need to use symbolic math at all in this case. Simple [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) would suffice, e.g.:

```
Vo = @(Ps,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd)(1/10^((LdB*(2*n + 3))/10)*BWc*Ps*Ro*Rpd)/BWs;
Ps = @(Vo,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd)(10^((LdB*(2*n + 3))/10)*BWs*Vo)/(BWc*Ro*Rpd);
```

Note that there is no problem with scope here in the naming of the functions. If the other arguments aren't changing, you can make these just a function of `Vo` and `Ps`:

```
BWc = ...
BWs = ...
Ro = ...
n = ...
LdB = ...
Rpd = ...
Vo = @(Ps)(1/10^((LdB*(2*n + 3))/10)*BWc*Ps*Ro*Rpd)/BWs;
Ps = @(Vo)(10^((LdB*(2*n + 3))/10)*BWs*Vo)/(BWc*Ro*Rpd);
```

Or you could create a single regular function that handles either input:

```
function out=VoPs(name,value,BWc,BWs,Ro,n,LdB,Rpd)
if (ischar(name) && strcmp(name,'Ps')) || (isa(name,'sym') && logical(name==sym('Ps')))
    Ps = value;
    Vo = Ps*(BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd;
elseif (ischar(name) && strcmp(name,'Vo')) || (isa(name,'sym') && logical(name==sym('Vo')))
    Vo = value;
    Ps = Vo/((BWc/BWs)*Ro*(10^((-(3+2*n)*LdB)/10))*Rpd);
else
    error('VoPs:InvalidName','Name input must be ''Vo'' or ''Ps''.')
end
```

Comment: You can use `matlabFunction` to convert symbolic expressions into anonymous functions (or standalone functions) as well. It can help performance if you will be using the function many times.

Comment: If one really wants performance, a hand crafted solution based on the symbolic function will often beat `matlabFunction`. I have a personal aversion to it, but it is convenient, performs vectorization automatically, and many may not be capable of creating efficient code (but if you don't try you won't learn anything).

Comment: Thank you I did not consider anonymous functions but it is the best solution for me.